# How can I use https protocol on AWS Load Balancer URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-acm

I made a AWS Load Balancer for a simple ECS fargate server (with flask). Because the server will be used as my main server's api, and because the main server use 'https', I have to use **https** on my Load Balancer's url.

But when I want to make SSL certificate using ACM, I can't verify the URL of Load Balancer is mine because the load balancer has any information (I think).

If I add my email info on the url(or Load Balancer), I can do this, but I have no idea..
Until now, I thought using AWS Route 53 can help me, but I don't know what I have to do.

What Can I do for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use ACM you need to have control of the domain you're attempting to validate, as the load balancer URL is owned by Amazon (not yourself), only an Amazon employee with domain control is capable of performing the actions to validate the domain.

Instead you would need to generate an ACM certificate for your own domain which you can validate, you would then need to add a DNS record resolving the domain to the CNAME of the load balancer. When you access in the browser you would need to access from that domain and not the load balancers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I understand, I need another domain (with HTTPs) and connect my load balancer url with that, and access with that domain. Then I can access the Load Balancer's server with HTTPs. Is that correct?